# How do I define a custom type with the oo7 Substrate library?

Tags: blockchain, substrate

I am using the Substrate Bonds library (oo7) to generate custom UI for my custom Substrate Runtime Module.

To support my custom module in the Substrate UI, I need to define a custom type. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oo7 Substrate library exposes the `addCodecTransform()` function which enables you to define custom types which you can then use within the UI.

For example, given this structure defined in your module:

```rust
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Default, Clone, PartialEq)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug))]
pub struct Kitty<Hash, Balance> {
    id: Hash,
    dna: Hash,
    price: Balance,
    gen: u64,
}
```

You could make the following JavaScript call:

```
addCodecTransform('Kitty<Hash,Balance>', { 
    id: 'Hash',
    dna: 'Hash',
    price: 'Balance',
    gen: 'u64'
});
```

If you add this do your applications `constructor()` function, you can make sure that it is called before your dependent React functions require it.